# How to Make Script Run Upon Root Login [Lubuntu]

Tags: scripts, lubuntu, startup, lxde, lxterminal

I need to know how to make a script run upon the login of root.

I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to Linux, so, simple terms please.

Also, I'm not doing this on the standard Ubuntu operating system, I'm doing it on Lubuntu, the lighter version of Ubuntu, that uses the LXDE enviroment. I'm not sure if that makes any difference or not.

Comment: Can be tricky, as login to room can be done via su, sudo, via console, other means

Comment: When you said "room", did you mean root? Because I have the root account enabled, and set to automatically login when the system starts.

Comment: Yes, root. Typing on phone can be tricky :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnKOd.png)

After enough rampaging across the internet, I eventually found the answer, thanks to @Sopalajo de Arrierez.

Because of Stack Exchange's dumb newbie rules, I can't embed the picture in this answer, so I included a link instead. ^

Normally I would delete this question and move on with my life, but I spent WAY to long trying to find the answer to this, and I would rather not have someone else with the same problem go through the pain of finding the answer like I did.